# Incorrect SQL Syntax - Unclosed quotation mark after the character string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Now i have string `a = "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '%Bamboo.Widgets.RequestApproval.CollectTask   ORDER BY Date DESC'.  Incorrect syntax near '%Bamboo.Widgets.RequestApproval.CollectTask   ORDER BY Date DESC'."` for filter

I'm using replace ("'","''") 
          replace ("%","[%]")
          replace ("[","[[]")

and I have as a result for string strSQL =

```
select * from studiologs 
where [Message] 
like '%Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''%Bamboo.Widgets.RequestApproval.CollectTask   ORDER BY Date DESC''.  Incorrect syntax near ''%Bamboo.Widgets.RequestApproval.CollectTask   ORDER BY Date DESC''.%'
```

but result always is null 
please help me replace this string for filter

thanks all

Answer (score 1):

I think you have missed one more quotation mark at end of query -

```
select * from studiologs where [Message] like '%Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''%Bamboo.Widgets.RequestApproval.CollectTask ORDER BY Date DESC''%'
```

or remove that last quotation mark as well, if your string does not have '

```
select * from studiologs where [Message] like '%Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''%Bamboo.Widgets.RequestApproval.CollectTask ORDER BY Date DESC%'
```

Depending on what you are searching exactly

Comment: Thanks , but now i used condition like %paramenter% 
select * from studiologs 
where [Message] 
like '%Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''%Bamboo.Widgets.RequestApproval.CollectTask   ORDER BY Date DESC''.  Incorrect syntax near ''%Bamboo.Widgets.RequestApproval.CollectTask   ORDER BY Date DESC''.%'
i think error at % character but i cannot fix it . please help me

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please run both the queries from my answer and see if you still get the error. You should not get any.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing I would do here is to transfer your SQL query into a procedure, that way the string you give it wont need filtering as the punctuation in the string *will not* affect the syntax of the query.

So something like this:

```
USE MYDATABASE
CREATE PROC GET_STUDIO_LOGS
@INPUT_STRING AS NVARCHAR(1024)
AS 
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM STUDIOLOGS WHERE [Message] LIKE '%' + @INPUT_STRING + '%'
END


EXEC GET_STUDIO_LOGS 'Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''%Bamboo.Widgets.RequestApproval.CollectTask ORDER BY Date DESC''. Incorrect syntax near ''%Bamboo.Widgets.RequestApproval.CollectTask ORDER BY Date DESC''.'
```

If you use a program to submit the SQL then you can submit the string parameter as it is without any change in punctuation. Doing it natively in SQL you just add another `'` (quotemark) to each quotemark that is meant to be part of the string.

If you are trying to escape the % marks you can set an escape character first:

```
SET ESCAPE '\';
SELECT '\%abc' FROM Table
```

Try that out, tell me how it goes.

Comment: I had try with Query SQL 
select * from studiologs 
where [Message] 
like '%\[Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '%Bamboo.Widgets.RequestApproval.CollectTask   ORDER BY Date DESC'.  Incorrect syntax near '%Bamboo.Widgets.RequestApproval.CollectTask   ORDER BY Date DESC'.]%' ESCAPE '\'

but result always null
Please tell me why ?

Comment: You need to use the Escape character before each function character you are needing to escape. So before each string based `%` and each string based `'`

So changing it to:

`select * from studiologs where [Message] like '%\[Unclosed quotation mark after the character string \'\%Bamboo.Widgets.RequestApproval.CollectTask ORDER BY Date DESC\'\. Incorrect syntax near \'\%Bamboo.Widgets.RequestApproval.CollectTask ORDER BY Date DESC\'\.\]%' ESCAPE '\'`

That should do the trick assuming you need to *keep* the first and last `%` in the `Like` statement.